# Are there any organizations or political movements in the US that promote Borda Count Ranked Voting?

Tags: united-states, voting-systems, plurality-voting-system

After researching [Borda Count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_count) Ranked Voting I realized that this voting system is something that I really support. I then researched organizations, political movements, and influential politicians that support this form of ranked voting but was unable to find any significant causes. I also looked at [FairVote](http://www.fairvote.org/) but that organization supports Instant Runoff Voting and not Borda Count. Are there any political organizations that support implementing Borda Count Ranked Voting in the United States?

Comment: This seems like the way to get the least disliked candidate elected not the best or favorite

Comment: There are a couple groups supporting Range Voting (also known as Score Voting), which is similar.

Comment: From what I've read, Borda is very vulnerable to strategic voting.  Borda: "My scheme is intended for only honest men"